# MySql Trigger if insert

Tags: mysql

Currently I've a cron job which runs each 5 minutes and always populates: record_id, timestamp and heating status (1 and 0) in 'data' table.

I want to create a trigger which on insert to 'data' table will be capturing first occurrence of heating status '1' (heating on) and inserts data to 'heating_data' table (record_id_on, timestamp and heating_on , it needs to stay dormant until heating is set to '0' (heating off), then it should trigger update to last row and insert timestamp_off and heating_off.

```
DELIMITER //

create TRIGGER heating_data_insert 
AFTER INSERT  ON nest_stats.data 
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN   
    DECLARE id_exists Boolean;
        select 1    
        into @id_exists    
        from nest_stats.data    
        where record_id= new.record_id    
        and heating  = 1 

        ;

        if @id_exists = 1     

    then         
        insert nest_stats.heating_data             
        SET record_id_on= (select max(record_id) from nest_stats.data),
        device_serial_number=new.device_serial_number,
        user_id=new.user_id,
        timestamp_on=new.timestamp,
        heating_on=new.heating;

    END IF;                          

        select 2    
        into @id_exists    
        from nest_stats.data    
        where record_id= new.record_id
        and heating  = 0 ;

        if @id_exists = 2                          

    then         
        update nest_stats.heating_data             
        SET record_id_off= new.record_id,             
        timestamp_off=new.timestamp,             
        heating_off=new.heating             
        where record_id_on =(select max(record_id_on) from nest_stats.data); 
    END IF; 
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
<code>
```

Comment: And your problem is....

Comment: Problem is that this trigger keeps inserting new row when next cron runs and return has heating set to 1, and I don't know how to make it to work as per description?

Comment: I'm sorry... I don't understand what you want to do nor why your trigger looks like that (perhaps it reflects your phrasing, but ...).

Answer (score 0):

I did the following changes and worked for me.

```
DECLARE id_exists Boolean;  

SELECT EXISTS(select record_id from nest_stats.data    
        where record_id= new.record_id    
        and heating  = 1) into @id_exists;

 IF @id_exists THEN
```